# Getting my SQL down to the latest Record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a SQL issue. I am getting duplicate records. I am also getting multiple records because of different dates. Here is an example of the data:

[image: Sample SQL Data]

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent, a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId, b.AppealOutcomeDate
FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealsLevel a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AppealLevelId, AppealOutcomeId,AppealOutcomeDate
    FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode
    WHERE AppealLevel = 1
    ) b
ON (AppealLevelId = a.AppealsLevelId)
WHERE Level = 1
```

I would like to show the null record if there isn't a matching record with a date. Other than that I would like to show the most recent `AppealOutcomeDate`.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to show the null record if there isn't a matching record with a date.

If you want to include NULL values, then you probably need a LEFT OUTER JOIN (or just "LEFT JOIN"):

```
SELECT a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent, a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId, b.AppealOutcomeDate
FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealsLevel a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AppealLevelId, AppealOutcomeId,AppealOutcomeDate
    FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode
    WHERE AppealLevel = 1
) b
ON (AppealLevelId = a.AppealsLevelId)
WHERE Level = 1
```

For more information about joins, I recommend Jeff Atwoord's [CODING HORROR: A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

> I would like to show the most recent AppealOutcomeDate.

If the date is the only column with a changing value in your duplicates, then you can just use a simple `GROUP BY` on all of the other columns and select the `MAX(AppealOutcomeDate)`

```
SELECT a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent, a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId, MAX(b.AppealOutcomeDate)
FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealsLevel a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT AppealLevelId, AppealOutcomeId,AppealOutcomeDate
    FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode
    WHERE AppealLevel = 1
) b
ON (AppealLevelId = a.AppealsLevelId)
WHERE Level = 1
GROUP BY a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent, a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId
```

If the other columns' value are changing (in relation to the changing date), and it's the join which is causing duplicate data, then you can add a subquery to your JOIN's ON clause:

```
SELECT a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent, a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId, b.AppealOutcomeDate
FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealsLevel a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT AppealLevelId, AppealOutcomeId,AppealOutcomeDate
    FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode
    WHERE AppealLevel = 1
) b
 ON AppealLevelId = a.AppealsLevelId
AND AppealOutcomeDate = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(AppealOutcomeDate)
        FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode
        WHERE AppealLevel = 1
          AND AppealLevelId = a.AppealsLevelId
    )
WHERE Level = 1
```

Comment: Your second example is so close to what I need. The only other problem is that it shows duplicate records. I used the 'DISTINCT' keyword and that fixed the problem! This did it! Thanks JDB!

Comment: @TravisGrannan - Like I said, the second example will only work if it's the join which is creating the duplicate data. Sounds like there is duplicate data in main table (before the join).

Comment: @JBD - Not annoyed at all, I was repaying the service.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead so you can include the null row, and you can use a NOT EXISTS clause to eliminate all but the maximum-date record:

```
SELECT a.RacLetterId, a.AppealsLevelId, b.AppealLevelId, a.Level, a.DateSent,
    a.DeliveryService, b.AppealOutcomeId, b.AppealOutcomeDate
FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealsLevel a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode b ON a.AppealsLevelId = b.AppealLevelId
    AND b.AppealLevel = 1
WHERE a.Level = 1
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.tbl_Tab_AppealCode bb
    WHERE bb.AppealLevelId = b.AppealLevelId
    AND bb.AppealLevel = 1
    AND bb.AppealOutcomeDate > b.AppealOutcomeDate
)
```